# Analytical expressions for the orthogonalization of a specific set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-mathematics, orthogonality, matrix-decomposition, time-series

I would like to know whether analytical or closed-form expressions could be obtained for the orthogonalization of a set of vectors in the following setting.

Let $x_t$ be a vector indexed as a time series observed at times 
$t=1,2,\dots,n$. Upon this vector, the following vectors are defined:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{array}{l}
y_{1,t} = (1 + L + L^2 + L^3) x_t \,, \\
y_{2,t} = -(1 - L + L^2 - L^3) x_t \,, \\
y_{3,t} = -(1 - L^2) x_t \,, \\
y_{4,t} = y_{3,t-1} \,,
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

where $L$ is the lag operator such that $L^i x_t = x_{t-i}$. These are the so-called HEGY regressors [1]. An alternative representation of these vectors is given in [2]:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{array}{l}
y_{1,t} = \sum_{i=0}^3 x_{t-i} \,, \\
y_{2,t} = \sum_{i=0}^3 \cos \left[ (i+1)\pi \right] x_{t-i} \,, \\
y_{3,t} = \sum_{i=0}^3 \cos \left[ (i+1) \pi/2 \right] x_{t-i} \,, \\
y_{4,t} = -\sum_{i=0}^3 \sin \left[ (i+1) \pi/2 \right] x_{t-i} \,.
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

The vectors $y_{1,t}$, $y_{2,t}$, $y_{3,t}$, $y_{4,t}$ can be computed independently of each other using the data in the vector $x_t$. That is, in order to obtain for example $y_{2,t}$, the remaining vectors need not be computed.

I want to find a set of orthogonal vectors that generate the same subspace as the vectors $y_{1,t}$, $y_{2,t}$, $y_{3,t}$, $y_{4,t}$. I can compute the four vectors $y_{1,t}$, $y_{2,t}$, $y_{3,t}$ and $y_{4,t}$ and apply a **numerical algorithm**, for example the Gram-Schmidt procedure or Householder transformations. However, I'm interested in **analytical expressions** that could allow me to compute one of the orthogonal vectors without allocating memory space for the remaining vectors.

In a given application, I want to limit the amount of required memory space. I don't need to compute the whole set of orthogonal vectors at the same time because they are used at different steps. That's why I'm interested in analytical expressions that could allow me to save memory space.

Is it possible to obtain analytical expressions for a set of orthogonal vectors that span the same subspace as that spanned by $y_{1,t}$, $y_{2,t}$, $y_{3,t}$, $y_{4,t}$? If so, could those expressions be written as a function of only the vector $x_t$?

---

**References**

[1] Kwiatkowski, D., Phillips, P.C.B., Schmidt, P., Shin, Y. (1992).
Testing the Null Hypothesis of Stationarity against the Alternative of a Unit Root. *Journal of Econometrics* **54**(1-3), pp. 159-178,
DOI: [10.1016/0304-4076(92)90104-Y](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-4076(92)90104-Y).

[2] Smith, R.J., Taylor, A.M.R., del Barrio Castro, T. (2009). 
Regression-based seasonal unit roots.  *Econometric Theory* 25, pp. 527-560.
DOI: [10.1017/S0266466608090166](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0266466608090166).
Granger Centre Discussion Paper No. 07/05 http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/6245791.pdf.

Comment: You could write out the formula for Gram-Schmidt explicitly, as there always $4$ vectors. However, it gets rather lengthy. Also notice that Gram-Schmidt is numerically unstable.

Comment: @user251257 Thanks for the idea. I am willing to accept lengthy computations but I think this would be too much in my application. In addition, if I understood correctly, I would still need to allocate memory for the first $i$ vectors when I want to compute the orthogonal vector related to $y_{i,t}$. Analytical expressions or some kind of transformation in the original vectors would be preferable.

Comment: what exactly do you do in your application? what are the computational and memory constraints?

Comment: @user251257 I am running several regressions where the vectors $y_{i,t}$ are the regressors. The regressions are run in parallel on a graphical processor unit, i.e., they are computed simultaneously by different threads. There is plenty of memory to compute one of these regressions but the purpose is to run as many of them as possible in parallel. The less memory is required by each regression the more threads will be able to run simultaneously.